# Laravel 5 - calling create() on hasMany relationship with conditions

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a couple of models - let's call them Item and Ean. In Item model there are a couple of hasMany relations to the Ean model.

```
  public function eans() {
    return $this->hasMany(Ean::class)->orderBy('type', 'asc')->orderBy('id', 'asc');
  }

  public function eans_type_1() {
    return $this->hasMany(Ean::class)->where('type', 1)->orderBy('id', 'asc');
  }

  public function eans_type_2() {
    return $this->hasMany(Ean::class)->where('type', 2)->orderBy('id', 'asc');
  }
```

When I want to associate a new Ean model to the Item, I'm using create() :

```
$item->eans()->create(['ean' => $value, 'type' => 1]);
or
$item->eans()->create(['ean' => $value, 'type' => 2]);
```

Is there a way to define hasMany relation in a way that I'll be able to do this :

```
$item->eans_type_1()->create(['ean' => $value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without some serious overriding. When you call

```php
$items->eans()
$items->eans_type_1()
$items->eans_type_2()
```

You're getting an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` instance and when you call

```php
$items->eans
$items->eans_type_1
$items->eans_type_2
```

You're getting an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance.
Just pass the value.